# VBA Dropdown Menu to other sheets : invalid use me keyword

Tags: vba, excel

I have a VBA code that I need to use a combobox to link to other sheets. The value is in the menu list. However when I perform this code I get an error "invalid use me keyword".

```
Sub Macro1()
Sheets(Me.navmenu.Value).Select  End Sub
```

Not sure what I am doing wrong in this procedure. Is there a fix ?

Appreciate any help.:)

Comment: `Debug.Print Me.navmenu.Value`  What does it give you?

Comment: Where is this code located ?

Comment: Hi Tim, I have it in a new spreadsheet I am creating from scratch. If it works I will implement in another one.

Comment: Debug.Print Me.navmenu.Value gives me : compilation error, syntax error

Comment: I mean is your code in a regular module, a sheet module, in a userform, in `ThisWorkbook` ?

Comment: Hi Tim the code is in a regular module.

Comment: In a sheet module, `Me` refers to the worksheet object; in a form it refers to the form.  In a regular module it doesn't refer to anything, hence the error you're seeing.  Where is your combobox ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your combobox is the "forms" type then you can use this code in a regular module:

```
Sub Navigate()

    'Application.Caller returns the name of the shape which called the Sub
    With ActiveSheet.Shapes(Application.Caller).ControlFormat
        ThisWorkbook.Sheets(.List(.ListIndex)).Select
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: Great Tim ! Worked perfectly. Thanks a Lot :)